# can we authorize vscode using session id? because i am not able to authorize , it gives error that no event found

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, authorization, session-id

Hi so i am trying to authorize the my org in vscode using the below documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_existing_access_token.htm

but it gives error while using this command

```
sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath <source-dir> --targetusername <access-token>
```

on the place of `<source-dir>` i am adding localpath of my project and in place of `<access-token>` , i am adding access token
but it return an error **event not found**

Comment: If its not working with SFDX, you can try native way https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332032&mode=1&type=1 

With this you can use above link to login and then use `sfdx force:auth:web:login` to connect with user name and password. Then you need not to worry abt sessionid

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to use access token, instead of just authorizing a user as @YsrShk suggests?

Comment: obviously there is a reason why i am authorizing vs code  using session id, as i dont have login credentials and i just work on clients project using session id only

Comment: @MohammedsaeedBaig - in that case try one thing, try to ask client to login on his system using below command - `sfdx force:org:display -verbose` and it generates a URL(SFDX AUTH URL), which you can store in a txt file and login like this - `sfdx auth:sfdxurl:store -f <path-to-sfdxAuthUrl-txt-file> -s -a MyDefaultOrg`

Answer (score 2):

A command was recently added to the Salesforce Extension pack to authorize an org using a session ID.  Look for 'SFDX: Authorize an Org using Session ID' from the command palette.

Comment: Thanks, man I was looking for this for a day.